# How do I get a variable from user input?

Tags: python

I have a variable called `name` the has a variable name in it, how would I get the value of the variable. Could I use `globals()`?

I have a thing making it like this, I just need to get the value of the variable:

```py
globals()[name] = data
```

`data` is unknown since this is for a programing language

Comment: Please provide some code to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you want to get the value of set the value? Either way your solution should already work

Comment: I need to get the value since it will already be made by the user